# VBA / Excel: How to allow user to add new line using a dropdown choice

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a simple request form that brings user to a spreadsheet where they are asked to fill out First Name, Last Name, User's Alias, Access to Deactivate and Role to Deactivate. The form could be used for up to 9 different users. I'd like to include another column saying "New Line for the Same User?" where a drop-down menu with answers "yes" and "no" would be available. And, if user select "yes", a new line would populate with the same Name and Alias like the row before, while other rows below it would move down by one row. The thing is I'd like to:

1) create a new line, but

2) copy only First Name (Column A), Last Name (Column B) and User's Alias (Column C) of that user. The "Access to Deactivate" option (column D) and the "Role to Deactivate" option would remain empty so the requester can fill them out. And the "New Line for the Same User" option would be not filled out as well in the new, copied row.

Here's a screenshot of what I have in mind: [image]

I've tried different approaches using VBA but since I am not that experienced, I couldn't come up with anything working exactly for the need. I believe it should be a dynamic-range-based so it works throughout the form. Could you please advise?

Comment: This is somehow easy, but because this is not a free code web, you should show us what you got. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.  If you're just looking for advice on how to get started, look into the Worksheet_Change event.  Info about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel).

Comment: Split your task into logical steps and write those steps down. They should not be divisible any further and follow one after another. Then google each step using "vba STEPNAME example", and you will find lots of code. Try out that code. If you get stuck on a specific spot within the found code, update your question with the code at hand and a specific descritpion of the problem. We will be happy to help you there. We will not write code for you, but help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F7:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Copy .Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":C" & Target.Row + 1)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```